# how to run jar file methods in jsp

Tags: jsp, jar

i am trying to run jar file methods in my jsp,i have properly set the build path for jar and saved that jar in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
 when i m trying to run jsp i am getting this error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

here is the code where i am calling the jar method.

```
<%
    GenericLog gl=new GenericLog();
    String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
    gl.write(uname);//jar file method which i am calling
    gl.write(pass);
%>
```

please suggest any solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you import `GenericLog.class` file in your jsp file?
Like

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
```

In above, it is importing all class file under java.util in jsp page. See [example](http://www.jsptut.com/directives.jsp)

Comment: yes i have import in my code here is code  <%@ page import="com.esign.genericlog.*" %>

Answer (score 0):

Keep the jar files in the Web/Inf folder and check method name should be public.